# Django: How to create a homepage with a table list of images, clicking on image should bring up respective details of the person

Tags: django, python-3.x

Using Django how do I create a homepage with a table list of images, clicking on image should bring up respective details of the person.

Basically I have small team of 50 members and I need to create a portal where the homepage shows the pics of the members in a table/grid and clicking on those members should bring up the details of them.

In Django, I could create a model with necessary information like name, gender, address etc (following the tutorial) and I could see that in the admin page.
Now I need to create a front end to show that in browser homepage like I said above, but I'm lost now..not sure how to go about it.

Please help! Give some guidance.

Thanks in advance,
Anantha

Comment: Please, make more precise questions. What have you tried? Can you break down the problem into something smaller?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct what you said about the model. You can have a single model like so

```
class Members(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ....
```

So the front-end is pretty easy too. All you need to do is create two views, one for the homepage and the other for the member details.

```
def homepage(request):
    context_dict = {}
    members = Members.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    context_dict['members'] = members
    # You can have any other context dictionary that you want to query.
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context_dict,)

def member_detail(request, member_id):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        member = Members.objects.get(id=member_id)
        context_dict['member'] = member
    except Members.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('homepage')
    return render(request, 'member_details.html', context_dict,)
```

Now you're ready to create your homepage and members details template. Since you have the query to the Members model in both of your views
you can now show all the information you need from both views, let's start with the homepage.

*homepage.html*

```
{% for member in members %}
{{ member.name }}
<img src="{{ member.image }}" />
<a href="{% url 'member_detail' member.id %}" /> # Goes to the members detail page 
{% endfor %}
```

For the `member_details.html` you can do the same thing. Start querying to all the fields that you want to show.

You'll need create a url for the `member_detail` view since you are using member_id to send to the url to take you to the member that you clicked on.

*urls.py*

```
url(r"^member/(?P<member_id>\d+)/$", views.member_detail, name="member_detail"),
```